# &(array[index]) vs (array + index)

Tags: c++, array, comparative-review, pointers

So I'm working with a function that returns a pointer to a list item. Right now, I'm using:

```
IYamlEntity* YamlList::operator[](int key)
{
    // Check for out-of-bounds.
    if (key < 0 || key >= _items.size()) return nullptr;
    return &(_items[key]); // **<- Line of interest.**
}
```

Would the following be better?

```
IYamlEntity* YamlList::operator[](int key)
{
    // Check for out-of-bounds.
    if (key < 0 || key >= _items.size()) return nullptr;
    return (_items + key); // **<- Line of interest.**
}
```

I know that they're functionally identical, but which one is "best practice"?

Comment: You're presented two code snippets with one specific difference. According to the [help/on-topic], "What is the best practice regarding _X_?" questions are off-topic.

Comment: The best one is that one that conveys the most meaning to the reader (not the writer). But the real question is why you are returning a pointer and not  a reference. In comparison both the above are worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with:

```
return (_items + key);
```

My reason for recommending this is that it is possible to overload the addressof operator, `&`. If that were the case,

```
return &(_items[key]);
```

could potentially be different and incorrect.

Both methods will work equally well if `operator&` is not overloaded but only the first one will work if it is.